# How to fix run time error 13 type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code to filter data between 2 date this code every time try to run giving me a message
run time error 13 type mismatch

This code is in the worksheet, not the module

```
Sub BetweenDates()    '(Filter data between 2 dates )
Dim sDate As Long
Dim EDate As Long

sDate = Range("B4").Value
EDate = Range("D4").Value

Range("c7:c80").AutoFilter 3, ">=" & sDate, xlAnd, "<=" & EDate
End Sub
```

Comment: Error *on which line*?

Comment: I don't know, How to know that?

Comment: Which line is highlighted when you click "Debug" after the error pops up?

Comment: No, any highlighted line

Comment: Then maybe the error is somewhere else.  What setting to you have under *VBeditor >> Tools >> Options >> General tab >> Error trapping*?  Make sure it's set to "Break in class module" then try again.

Comment: try `Range("c7:c80").AutoFilter 3, ">=" & CDate(sDate), xlAnd, "<=" & CDate(EDate)`

Comment: @TimWilliams After I set error trapping to  "Break in class module" start highlighted line sDate = Range("B4").Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to reproduce this error if range B4 or D4 is NOT a date.

You might have text or something else in those cells.

In cells B4 and D4 make sure the number format is General or Date, then enter the dates again.

Edit:

Using text boxes makes will make it more complex, so consider if you can use cells instead. But if you really do need to use text boxes:

Instead of

```
sDate = Range("B4").Value
EDate = Range("D4").Value
```

You will need to use:

```
sDate = DateValue(ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text)
EDate = DateValue(ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 2").TextFrame.Characters.Text)
```

and you will need to replace the "TextBox 1", "TextBox 2" with whatever your text boxes are named.

If you don't know what your text boxes are named, you can use the following:

```
Sub list_shapes()

Dim sh As Shape

For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    Debug.Print sh.Name, DateValue(sh.TextFrame.Characters.Text)
Next sh

End Sub
```

Keep in mind the above will only work if the user types full dates into the text boxes. If they enter "1-Jul-23" it will work, but if they enter "1-Jul" it will not work.

The above will also only work if the user has the sheet active when the macro is run.

Comment: Thank you I found the error and I want to link  this code to the textbox instead to cell